# StackExchange APIを使ったアプリケーション開発でのテスト方法

Tags: サポート

StackExchange APIを使ってアプリケーションを開発しています。
しかし、テストをする方法がありません。
`{user_id}/inbox/unread`を使っているのですがどのようにテストすればいいのでしょうか?
何かテスト用のBOTのようなものはないのでしょうか?

Comment: 確認してみます。基本的に開発したものを[StackApps](https://stackapps.com/)に登録し、それで使えるようになると思いますが、念のために確認させていただきます。特にテスト環境について聞いてみます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**APIキーを獲得**

[StackApps](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register)で登録すれば、APIキーを与えます。テストのためにも登録できますし、appは完了したらそのアプリを公開することができます。

**キーを利用してOAuthで認証**

キーがあれば、それを利用し[OAuthでトークン](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication)がもらえます。それでinbox等をテストすることができます。

---

もし追加の質問等あれば、ご教示ください（弊職はAPIにあまり詳しくないが、社内で相談します）。

Comment: （APIをテストするために[Meta.SEのスレ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812/the-api-sandbox)もあります）

Comment: inbox/unreadを取得して処理するためにはinboxに未確認のアイテムが必要ですが、それらは何かしらの質問やコメントを投稿して、それに対して他のユーザから反応がないとできません。
何かinboxのdummyなアイテムを作成する方法はありますか?

Comment: @KiYugadgeter 日本語版のメタなら信用度ゼロでも投稿できるので、新アカウントを作成しても問題ないです（もちろん自分の他の投稿等を投票してはいけませんが・・・）。それかチャットで他のユーザーにお願いすることも可能です。まだ難しいならここに返事して、出来る範囲に支援させていただきます。

Comment: 自動でコメントなどをしてくれるbotをどこか特別なページに置くことは可能ですか?

Comment: @KiYugadgeter  ボット等はないです。テストのためにテストアカウント作れば一番らくだと思います。